# Git branch name terminal error "\u@\h \[\033[32m\]\w\[\033[33m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]"

Tags: git, macos, terminal, git-branch

I added this in my `bash_profile`

```
# Git branch in prompt.
parse_git_branch() {
     git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
export PS1="\u@\h \[\033[32m\]\w\[\033[33m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
```

When I do `source ~/.bash_profile` I see this(below) and git branch name does not work. Can someone please help?

```
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
\u@\h \[\033[32m\]\w\[\033[33m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $
```

Comment: That's an `npm` warning, unrelated to git or the bash code you're showing.

Comment: @robertklep look at this part `\u@\h \[\033[32m\]\w\[\033[33m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]`

Comment: this is what I get after adding git branch code in my bash

Comment: @Gaurav, yes, that other part is your PS1, but what about it?

Comment: (also, printing your prompt wrong is not an error message)

Comment: As far as I understood OP wanted to demonstrate that the PS1 string is NOT parsed but printed literally character by character

Comment: @Jay yeah you're right, I was distracted by the npm warning (which is irrelevant to the actual issue)

Comment: @robertklep I was confused for a few seconds myself, until I realized it was supposed to be a "screenshot of the terminal" that shows how OP's PS1 looks in action :D

Comment: @Jay correct it is printing `\u@\h \[\033[32m\]\w\[\033[33m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] ` instead of git branch name. I am not sure if anything is wrong in my bash

Comment: how can I fix this?

Comment: @Gaurav If I put your code in my `.bashrc` it works perfectly fine. So I'm not sure what's the issue here. My `$SHELL --version` says `GNU bash, version 5.1.4`. Yours?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a recent version of macOS, your default shell is `zsh`, not `bash` (try running `echo $SHELL`). Because `zsh` has a (completely) different way of configuring prompts, you can't use bash-specific code.

Comment: I am using Monterey

Comment: Like I said, you can run `echo $SHELL` to find out which shell is your default shell.

Comment: thanks @robertklep `zsh` works for me now